# Why do we say that the sequence is bounded by $\max\{|a_{1}|,|a_{2}|,...,|a_{N-1}|,|a_{N}|+1\}$?

Tags: real-analysis

**Completeness Theorem**. A sequence of real numbers converges if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence. In particular, $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.

The following is part of the proof of the completeness theorem:

> **PROOF**. Suppose that $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence. First we show that the set $\{a_{n}:n \ge 1\}$ is bounded. Take $\epsilon =1$ and find $N$ sufficiently large that $$|a_{n}-a_{N}|<1 \hspace{0.5cm} \text{for all}\hspace{0.5cm} n \ge N$$
>
> It follows that the sequence is bounded by $$\max\{|a_{1}|,|a_{2}|,...,|a_{N-1}|,|a_{N}|+1\}$$.

I was wondering why we go through the process of finding the maximum of $|a_{1}|,|a_{2}|,...,|a_{N-1}|,$ and $|a_{N}|+1$ when from the triangle inequality we have that $$|a_{n}|=|a_{n}-a_{N}+a_{N}|\le |a_{n}-a_{N}| + |a_{N}|$$ and hence $$|a_{n}|-|a_{N}| \le |a_{n}-a_{N}|<1$$ by assumption. And so $$|a_{n}|\le |a_{n}-a_{N}|<1+|a_{N}|$$

Which means that the entire sequence is bounded by $1 + |a_{N}|$.

Comment: What if $a_n = \{100000,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots\}$? You know that for $n>N=2$ have have $|a_n-a_N| < 1$ however $|a_2| + 1 = 2$, but the sequence is not bounded by $2$ (but it is bounded by max$(|a_1|,|a_2|+1) = 100000$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your demonstration is true for all $n\gt N$.  However for $n \lt N$, $|a_n-A_N|$ may not be $\lt 1$.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about that.